# Get result of Adapter back to Activity

Tags: android, adapter, in-app-billing

I'm using the [anjlab in app billing library](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) to perform subscriptions in my app.

The purchase dialog is being called from the adapter like so:

**Adapter**

```
billingProcessor.subscribe(((Activity) context), "annual_subscription");
```

and from the documentation, you need to implement (code below) to get the result of the purchase back:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent
data) {
if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }  
}
```

I cannot override this method since its not an activity and the purchase can only happen from the adapter.

I've read about interfaces, but I still haven't gotten the concept, could you provide a simpler explanation on how I could achieve this to get the result back to the activity

Comment: Pass your activity's context to the adapter like `new MyAdapter(this)` then override `onActivityResult` in your activity wherein the listview is placed. `public MyAdapter(Activity activity)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1)you need one interface
2)implement interface in your activity
3)you have adapter reference in your activity,simply pass interface to your adapter.
4)in adapter you can call interface method,you will get the call in your activity.
```

its call the [java callback](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/callback-using-interfaces-java/)

Comment: I'm following on this, do I need to implement the interface in both the Adapter and the Activity?

Comment: No only in activity